# Consequences of coming clean on Visa Application/Interview

Tags: visas, usa, uk

My friend requires some travel advice. He has traveled quite a bit and over the years acquired many different visas to many different countries. The truth is that on most of his Visa applications including to the UK and USA he has told many significant untruth such as *6.3 Have you ever been refused a visa for any country, including the UK?* and also used false documents the most recent being sometime last year.

He will be applying for a UK visa this month. Should he proactively confess to these previous transgressions or continue in them since they have never been discovered? Is there some waiver of penalties if one proactively comes forward? What are the consequences of doing so? References will be helpful.

Comment: You're saying he used false documents with a UK visa application last year and now you're asking if he should admit to having done so on a new application? Really? Am I understanding that correctly? I can't imagine how that wouldn't result in a ban.

Comment: I think this guy needs to consult a lawyer if he really wants to go.  (Yes, that will probably cost a lot of money.)  Note that we have a general practice here of not advising people to violate the law, and lying on a visa application is definitely illegal.

Comment: I'd say the concern here isn't whether he would get into the UK again, it's whether the UK authorities would notify the local police of a fraud case if he admits to using false documents. [It happens](https://www.gov.uk/government/world-location-news/uk-visa-applicants-arrested-for-fraud), especially when forgeries are involved. He needs legal advice.

Comment: Why would he disclose the fact that false documents were previously used unless directly related to the new application?

Comment: It might be better to rephrase the question to ask what the likely and/or permitted penalties are for "coming clean" in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Travel.Stackexchange we typically advocate telling the truth, in this case consult an attorney. That is the best answer under the circumstances. They are the ones best equipped with the know how to unravel this tapestry if it is possible to do so with minimal consequences.